# C# dbcontext keeps returning null although data is available in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an API endpoint as shown:

```
[HttpGet("{language}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllClozeWords(string language)        
{
    var clozes = await GetClozesForLanguage<Cloze>(language);
    
    if (clozes.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
 
    return Ok();
}

private async Task<List<T>> GetClozesForLanguage<T>(string language) where T : Cloze 
{
    switch (language.ToLower())
    {
        case "nl":
            return await this._trackerDbContext.NLclozes.ToListAsync() as List<T>;

        case "en":
            return await this._trackerDbContext.ENclozes.ToListAsync() as List<T>;

        default:
            return new List<T>();
    }
}
```

And an Entity Framework model as shown:

```
public abstract class Cloze
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string cloze_word { get; set; }
}

public class NLcloze : Cloze
{
    public string note1 { get; set; }
    public string note2 { get; set; }
    public string note3 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NLexpression> NLexpressions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ENcloze> ENclozes { get; set; }
}

public class ENcloze : Cloze
{
    public string note1 { get; set; }
    public string note2 { get; set; }
    public string note3 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ENexpression> ENexpressions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NLcloze> NLclozes { get; set; }
}
```

When I hit the endpoint using a get request with the appropriate `language` argument e.g. `nl`, I keep on getting null on the return of the switch statement, although I have double checked that there is data inside the database.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: What does "getting null on the return of the switch statement" mean? What expression, specifically, is `null`?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best answer and i cant comment, but something to hopefully help you along:

Is "ToListAsync()" on each of actually bringing any data back? If so the problem would be the casting. If not, you could be looking at other issues such as connectivity to the DB.

So change the function to and see if you are getting anything back from the DB.

```
private async Task<List<T>> GetClozesForLanguage<T>(string language) where T : Cloze 
{
    switch (language.ToLower()){
        case "nl":
            var nl = await this._trackerDbContext.NLclozes.ToListAsync();
            return nl as List<T>;
        case "en":
            var en = await this._trackerDbContext.ENclozes.ToListAsync();
            return en as List<T>;
        default:
            return new List<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes indeed I think the problem is with casting, since when I tried the simpler answer given by Steve Py below, the IDE refuses to cast NLCloze and ENCloze to Cloze; I think because the result of the cast may be used to access the properties of ENCloze (for example), while it was casted from NLCloze. So I think it's like having a dog and cat inherit from animal, casting a cat to animal, and then asking the animal to bark. Maybe I should just get rid of the Cloze abstract class? But then I will have code duplication...

Comment: You can still use a base class for common code shared between the two, you just don't structure methods around using the common class when you are dealing with one or the other. Another thing that is probably tripping you up is the use of Generics. Generic classes are meant for code where the types are purely interchangeable. If you have situations where you want EnClozes vs NlClozes and those classes are significant to the operation then it's better to have two methods, GetEnClozes() and GetNlCloses(). Generic methods/code should not contain conditional type inference.

Comment: Two simpler methods that may have similar code specific to their type is far better than one generic method with `if/then'/`switch` statements then trying to cast down to a base class you cannot really consume.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that a generic implementation here is not needed and possibly causing you grief. At a minimum you should check with breakpoints whether your `case` scenarios are hit and whether the values read are what you expect.

That said, the generic casting isn't necessary with inheritance:

```
private async Task<List<Cloze>> GetClozesForLanguage(string language) 
{
    switch (language.ToLower())
    {
        case "nl":
            return await _trackerDbContext.NLclozes.ToListAsync();

        case "en":
            return await _trackerDbContext.ENclozes.ToListAsync();

        default:
            return new List<Cloze>();
    }
}
```

One problem you will run into with designs like this is loading/using related data to the resulting Clozes. For instance each type (En & Nl) have navigation properties to related data. The above method does not eager load this (nor really should it if there is a considerable amount of data in play) which will mean that these navigation properties (NLExpressions/EnExpressions/etc.) will either be left #null or lazy loaded.  This will be something to be wary of with your design and how you intend to use the information coming back.

Personally I would recommend externalizing the checking on language type and just going to the appropriate NlClozes or EnClozes DbSets so that callers can project or further eager load related data as they need rather than trying to return this data back as "Clozes" and then re-casting when they need related data.

Comment: Unfortunately using your example code, I cannot cast the `ENcloze` and `NLCloze` to `Cloze` somehow; the IDE complains with it unable to be casted so I cannot compile. I think it's because we're trying to cast a child class to a parent class, and so the IDE may be afraid that the result will be used to access properties special to ENcloze (for example) when it was casted from NLcloze.

Comment: Double check by using the "go to definition" that your class references in your calls for GetClozesForLanguage etc. are actually going to the same base class Entity for the Cloze and not some other defined DTO class definition or such, I've seen similar problems raised where the OP had an entity and DTO with the same name in different namespaces. If you have Cat & Dog extend Animal you should 100% be able to pass back Cats and/or Dogs in a set of Animal type references. Just not passing Animal references as Cat without using an `OfType<Cat>()` to filter just Cats.

Comment: found the error, turns out we need to return an IEnumerable instead of a list, since List<out T> doesn't exist but IEnumerable<out T> does. If you want to edit your answer I can accept it :)